# Unity save camera image at a specific rate

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my project, I am saving camera images to a folder, but it saves ~60 per second. How could I reduce the amount of images it saves to about 10 per second?

```
void Update()
{ 
    if (TLB)
    {
        DirectoryInfo p = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        FileInfo[] files = p.GetFiles();
        saveFrame(path, "TLB", fileCounter);
        fileCounter = files.Length + 1;
    }
}    

void saveFrame(string path, string type, int counter)
{
    RenderTexture rt = new RenderTexture(frameWidth, frameHeight, 24);
    GetComponentInChildren<Camera>().targetTexture = rt;
    Texture2D frame = new Texture2D(frameWidth, frameHeight, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
    GetComponentInChildren<Camera>().Render();
    RenderTexture.active = rt;
    frame.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, frameWidth, frameHeight), 0, 0);
    GetComponentInChildren<Camera>().targetTexture = null;
    RenderTexture.active = null;
    Destroy(rt);
    byte[] bytes = frame.EncodeToPNG();
    string filename = path + type + "/" + "/" + frameName(type, counter);
    File.WriteAllBytes(filename, bytes);
}
```

Comment: where are you calling the method? always add all the relevant code in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Repeating code execution after a certain time interval in Unity

---

**Using Update() method:**

```
// Invoke the method after interval seconds
public float interval = 0.1f;

// time counter
float elapsed = 0f;

void Update() 
{
    elapsed += Time.deltaTime;

    // if time is elapsed, reset the time counter and call the method.
    if (elapsed >= interval) 
    {
        elapsed = 0;
        TakeShot();
    }
}

void TakeShot() 
{
   // do your thing here...
}
```

---

**Using InvokeRepeating() method:**

```
// Invoke the method after interval seconds
public float interval = 0.1f;

float delaySeconds = 0f; // delay the first call by seconds

void Start()
{
    InvokeRepeating("TakeShot", delaySeconds, interval);
}

void TakeShot() 
{
   // do your thing here...
}
```

**NOTE:** Both methods are `framerate` and `time-scale` dependent.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: the condition in Update() is only true after `interval` seconds. This is a very basic approach to execute the code after a certain interval of time. You can also use InvokeRepeating method which does the same thing but without using Update()

Comment: It would be better to edit that to your answer. Code only answers are not helpful.